# complicated column calculation in mysql to get a count of monthly visits

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables that look like this

customer table

```
first last cust_id  
John Doe 0  
Jane Doe 1
```

ledger table

```
posted_date cust_id   
2014-01-14  0  
2014-01-20  0  
2013-12-20  0  
2013-12-20  1  
2013-11-12  1  
2013-11-10  1
```

I need to calculate the number of months where the customer posted a transaction at least once, this is being called CustomerMonths for the last 12 months.  This means CustomerMonths for each cust_id would be between 0 and 12.  So for this data I would want to see

```
cust_id CustomerMonths  
0 2  
1 2
```

This is because cust_id 0 was in at least once in Jan 2014 and at least once in Dec 2013.
Similarly, cust_id 1 was in at least once in Dec 2013 and at least once in Nov 2013.
For this example for cust_id 0:

```
2014-01-14,  
2014-01-20 = 1 CustomerMonths  
2013-12-20 = 1 CustomerMonths
```

so total CustomerMonths for last 12 months for cust_id 0 is 2.

I have this working for one month but not sure how to get this to work for the last 12 months.  Although I'd settle for it working for the last two months.  I think i could figure out the rest.  Here's what I have.

```
select distinct 
    c.cust_id,
    (case when count(lJan.posted_date) = 0 then 0 else
     case when count(lJan.posted_date) > 0 then 1 end end) as CustomerMonths
from 'customer' c
left join 'ledger' lJan on (lJan.cust_id = c.cust_id and lJan.posted_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31')
group by c.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count distinct months, so use `count(distinct)`.  The question is what is the argument.  Try this:

```
select c.cust_id,
       count(distinct year(l.posted_date) * 100 + month(l.posted_date)) as CustomerMonths
from customer c left join
     ledger l
     on l.cust_id = c.cust_id and
        l.posted_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-31'
group by c.cust_id;
```

Another way of writing the `select`:

```
select c.cust_id,
       count(distinct date_format(l.posted_date, '%Y-%m')) as CustomerMonths
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I tried it and it returns 0 or 1 for CustomerMonths never more than 1.  The year() and month() are new to me.  I looked them up but why the "* 100" for the year and "+ month()".

Comment: @user3272743 . . . What is your condition on the `posted_date`?  You need to include multiple months (as in the query).

Comment: sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm a novice.  I thought the condition was in the join .. on where it was between a date range.

Comment: @user3272743 . . . The condition is in the `join` (in the `on` clause). In the original query, it was only one month.  You need to be sure that you are getting more than one month.

Comment: I typed in the wrong year so it was based on one month so of course it was returning only 0 and 1.  Thanks after setting the correct range, it worked.  Really appreciate your help.